# CORS in Express works on Safari but not on Chrome

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I have an `Express` application running on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, for which I have enabled CORS by doing below in my entry point:

```
app.use(cors());
```

I can do a simple `POST` request to an endpoint in my server with Postman or in my React app on Safari, for logging in. I cannot do it on Google Chrome, unfortunately. This is what I get on console:

```
OPTIONS http://**.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/signin 0 ()
```

On network tab of developer tools, I have this:

[image: Error on network tab]

I do the API request in React as following:

```
const customHeader = () => ({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
  Accept: 'application/json',
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token') || undefined,
});

const base = (method, url, data = {}) => {
  return fetch(`${jwtConfig.fetchUrl}${url}`, {
    method,
    headers: customHeader(),
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => res)
    .catch(error => ({ error: 'Server Error' }));
};

const SuperFetch = {};
['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'].forEach(method => {
  SuperFetch[method] = base.bind(null, method);
});
export default SuperFetch;
```

And calling:

```
await SuperFetch.post('signin', userInfo)
```

The fact that it is working on Postman and Safari leads me to believe that it has something to do with Google Chrome. I also have [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en) enabled but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this flag as well:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization
```